# Check QCheckbox with enter/return

Tags: c++, qt, qcheckbox

I have a `QCheckbox` and which I'm trying to change the state using a keyboard press of return/enter, rather than space.

For other things such as QPushbuttons/QLineEdit, I've used `returnPressed()` in the signal, however this doesnt work for `QCheckbox` and none of the options seem suitable.

How do I change the state of the `QCheckbox` on return/enter press when it has focus.

The code I've tried is

```
QObject::connect(ui->operator_checkbox, SIGNAL(returnPressed()), 
 ui->operator_checkbox, SLOT(setChecked(true)));
```

Comment: Did you try to use keyPressEvent for your checkbox with Qt::Key_Enter Qt::Key_Return filter?

Comment: First and foremost: does this agree with the platform human interface guidelines for your system? If it doesn't, then adding such behaviors will be at the very least confusing to your users, and possibly lead to disastrous unintended consequences.

Comment: @demonplus - hadn't thought of that, thanks!

Comment: @KubaOber - yeah, pressing enter/return to select is more intuitive for the user than pressing space

Comment: How does every other piece of software behave on your platform, though?